# Perl Algorithm::Diff - treat predefined changes as unchanged

Tags: perl, text, comparison, diff, sdiff

I'm comparing a template to the output based on that template, so I need to produce sdiff output that is tolerant of specified changes; essentially I want the template line:

```
Foo bar blarg [TAG] lorem ipsum
```

to match any of

```
Foo bar blarg .+ lorem ipsum
```

rather than being reported as changed.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: On the face of it, preprocess the template line into the appropriate regular expression, and then compare the file line with the template-line-as-regex.  So, read a line from the template and convert it to a regex; read a line from the other file, and see if it matches the template regex.  That doesn't sound like Algorithm::Diff, though.  It also leaves you with resynchronization problems if your other file has extra lines or missing lines.

Comment: I'd like to use some form of the Diff module to take advantage of the minimal set of changes it returns.

Comment: Are you sure that none of your `[TAG]` values are multi-line strings?  If so, you can try using lines from the template modified into regular expressions to detect the expanded forms in the other file and replace the expansion with `[TAG]` notation, and then run a Diff algorithm on the template (original) file and the unexpanded version of the other file.  Otherwise, go scanning http://search.cpan.org/ for ideas.  If there isn't a module that does what you need, you could consider writing one, but it won't be trivial.  If you have multi-line replacements for tags, life is much harder.

Comment: I already do preprocessing to convert any multiline tags into multiple single-line tags.

Using the template to fix the output before comparison defeats the purpose of the diff step -- if I'm doing line-by-line comparison I might as well just do the comparison in those steps.

I'll have a look at search.cpan

Comment: Could you provide samples of your template and output files along with details of what should and shouldn't be considered as a difference? I suspect that you could use Algorithm::Diff::traverse_balanced and handle ignoring false positives in the callbacks for differences.